# Failed login when using post in cakephp 3.x?

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code:

UserController:

```
 public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->input('json_decode', true); 
        print_r($this->request->data);
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

In the app controller I have:

```
 public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginaction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ]
        ]);
}
```

To be honest the only real difference between the [blog authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) tutorial and this is the print_r statement and the input line that changes it from json to an array which I think is what Auth->identify() is expecting in the CakeRequest. I am using cake 3.2.

The print_r prints out

```
    Array
(
     [username] => test1234@gmail.com
     [password] => 1234
)
```

Comment: You've passed in `username` when you should pass in `email`
Be sure to check that you've got hashed passwords as Alimon said.

Comment: @JazzCat what you stated was correct after changing the key value it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
```

code for password encryption

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```

in src/Model/Entity/User.php

see again [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout)